# Restricting ubuntu signing keys?

Tags: gnupg, ubuntu

I started reading on apt and the security changes to always use GPG signing keys,
but further saw that it by default uses all configured GPG signing keys,
this seems like a small but unecessary loophole.
It looks to be standard for custom repositories to restrict the signing keys to its corresponding key.

However, I cannot seem to find anyone who restricts the standard repositories to their respective keys. What am missing?